# Extracting data from CSV to create xml

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have a csv file which contains a column in which there is a xml file stored.

```
   col1      |   col2    | col3
some data    | some data |<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

I am trying to extract this data and create xml files. Suppose there are 10 rows, so 10 xml files should be created. I am able to create 10 xml files but there is no data in the last one.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd,codecs,time
df = pd.read_csv(r'csv_file')
xml_file = df.col3
c=0
timeStamp = str(int(round(time.time())))
for i in xml_file:
    filename_r = codecs.open(("abc"+ timeStamp +str(c) + ".xml"), 'w','utf-8')
    c=c+1
    filename_r.write(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the file is not closed yet, you can use `with ... as` to handle this situation.

```
for i in xml_file:
    with codecs.open(("abc"+ timeStamp +str(c) + ".xml"), 'w','utf-8') as filename_r: 
        filename_r.write(i)
    c=c+1
```